# How to run /etc/init.d/functions without rebooting?

Tags: linux, centos

I added a line to /etc/init.d/functions and I want everything in /etc/init.d/functions to be run without me rebooting.

Is there a way for me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but you could try doing `init` with your current runlevel.  That may rerun all the init.d scripts, though it might recognize that it's already at that runlevel and skip it.  If it does what I expect it would restart all your services, or at least try to.

Also, I'm assuming since you're talking about `init.d` that you're using CentOS 6 or older.